# how to load page with onModuleLoad(), with timer

Tags: html, gwt

This should be a fairly easy question but I have yet to come across anything that is similar to .net, where an event can be fired when a page is loaded. Here @ GWT, there is onModuleLoad(). How do i go to another HTML page, say after 2 seconds?

The following page does it, but after the click of a button. I do not wish to click on any button. Just load another page when the initial page is loaded, automatically.

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT applications are one page applications. You are always in the same page. You can add the timer anywhere you like. For example you could add this at the end of onModuleLoad.

```
package com.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

public class TimerExample implements EntryPoint 
{
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() 
    {
        Timer t = new Timer() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                RootPanel.get().clear();  
                RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Bye"));
            }
        };

        // Schedule the timer to run once in 5 seconds.
        t.schedule(5000);

        RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("Hello"));
    }
}
```

You should also check this too:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html